# Using JS/JQuery in Vue.js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Can we not use our custom JS code in vue.js? I want to add basic jquery and JS code but seems like vue.js doesn't take it up. Do I need to create component for it?

This is my js code that I want to add

```
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/5.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('ID', {
      cluster: 'ap2',
      forceTLS: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Pusher Test</h1>
  <p>
    Try publishing an event to channel <code>my-channel</code>
    with event name <code>my-event</code>.
  </p>
</body>
```

This is how my vue.js code starts, I was under impression that it will work with no issues.

```
    <template>
    <div>  
    <div class="apps-backdrop in" @click="close" v-if="isOpen"></div>
    <div class="apps-sidebar" :class="{'in': isOpen}">
      <v-list three-line class="navy pa-0 pt-2">
        <v-subheader>
          <h3>Title</h3>
        </v-subheader>

        .....



<script>


import hopscotch from 'hopscotch';
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex';
import sites from '../../config/sites';
import api from '../api/users';


export default {
    name: 'pushercomponent',
    data () {

....
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Import jQuery in whichever component you want:

```
<script>
  import $ from 'jquery';

  export default {
    mounted() {
      $(".test").delay(3000).css("background-color","red");
    },
  };
</script>
```